# Нужна ли запятая после  однако?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда однако выделяется запятыми?

Comment: @bronik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить коротко, то "однако" НЕ выделяется запятой, когда оно стоит в начале предложения. В середине - выделяется, потому что является вводным словом.
Например, "Однако мне не все понятно в этом предложении" - тут в начале слова, следовательно запятой нет. Либо: "Мне, однако (же), не все понятно в этом предложении". Как видите, тут слово берется в запятые.